# Test fails in Foundry when using asterisk (*) for unpacking when creating a dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, tuples, pytest, palantir-foundry

I want to create a DataFrame in a fixture using the following code:

```
@pytest.fixture
def my_fun(spark_session):
    return spark_session.createDataFrame(
        [
            (*['test', 'testy'])
        ],
        T.StructType([
            T.StructField('mytest', T.StringType()),
            T.StructField('mytest2', T.StringType()
        ])
    )
 
def test_something(my_fun):
    return
```

However, this fails with the following error:

```
TypeError: StructType can not accept object 'test' in type <class 'str'>
```

If I use `('test', 'testy')` instead of `(*['test', 'testy'])`, it works. **But shouldn't this be synonymous?**

(I'm using Python 3.8.13, pytest-7.0.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not the same. The round brackets in your example are not a `tuple`, they are just round brackets around a `list`. To make it a `tuple` you need to add a comma

```
test = (*['test1', 'test2'],)
# ('test1', 'test2')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma.

If I run this basic example:

```
test = (*['test1', 'test2'])
```

It fails with:

```
File "file0.py", line 5
  test = (*['test1', 'test2'])
            ^
SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here
```

Try the following:

```
(*['test1', 'test2'],)
```

On another note: Is there a reason you want to spread the list instead of directly using a tuple?